# PC shutdowns due to slow CPU fan?

Tags: cpu, shutdown, fan

I am stuck in a weird problem. The CPU fan just works fine when I start my PC. But after sometime maybe **half an hour** the CPU fan runs extremely slow like for example it goes from (RPM **5000** to **150**). This is only for the reference because I does not know exact RPM of my CPU fan. This cause overheating in the processor and power down the PC. It happens every time.

Comment: How did you verify that the shutdown is due to overheating?

Comment: whenever the CPU fan goes slow, the PC gets shutdown after sometime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a mechanical problem with the CPU fan that is causing it to  malfunction and spin too slowly. It's much cheaper to replace a CPU fan than to replace the CPU. Stop using that computer and replace the CPU fan immediately before something else breaks.

[SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) is a system monitor for Microsoft Windows that can read temperatures, voltages and fan speeds of computer components. It can change computer fan speeds depending on the temperature of various components.